# Network Monitor Endpoint Agent?

Tags: networking

Looking for a low cost(free) network monitor for endpoints that will actively monitor network connections for ANY network related issue on itself or it's network segment.  I'm looking for more than a ping test from a centralized server.  The endpoint agent should monitor for traffic issues and connected port issues. It should also run little speed tests either internally or to a url on a schedule and alert on issues.  My goal is to never get a call from a user saying their internet is slow without me being alerted to that fact first.

Comment: And the OS of endpoints is? Moreover you need monitoring platform, endpoints are just endpoints...

Comment: Mostly Windows 11 and Chrome OS.  Just looking for more than a single server polling and pulling information from snmp.  Agents typically have access to better information and having alternate sources of monitoring has it's benefits too.

Comment: Usually monitoring agents are specific to to the monitoring platform. You can check Prometheus and compatible agents (for example `node_explorer` )